# Select a row to multiple rows, with row have another caculating

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `Allowance` (Name,  Value,Date, Allowance)

I have many row value, With one 'Name', I select 2 names

I write to script below

```
select s.name, coalesce(v.name, s.name) AS 'Name1'
from Allowance s left join
     (values ('A', 'Allowance1'),
             ('A', 'Allowance2')
     ) v(old_name, name)
     on v.old_name = s.name
```

and result:

```
 Name|  Name1       | Value    | Date
-----+--------------+----------+---------
 A   |  Allowance1  |          | 2019-01-01
 A   |  Allowance2  |          | 2019-01-01
```

With a values of column `Name1` with have other caculating (column `Value`)
Ex:

```
With Allowance1: I have a script
select sum(value) from Allowance where Allowance='1' group by Name
Result: 145

With Allowance2: I have a script
select sum(value) from Allowance where Allowance='1' or Allowance='2' group by Name

Result: 123
```

How to select result below ?

```
 Name|  Name1       | Value    | Date
-----+--------------+----------+---------
 A   |  Allowance1  |    145   | 2019-01-01
 A   |  Allowance2  |    123   | 2019-01-01
```

Please help me to resolve issue.

Comment: I don't see any question. Please add expected output

Comment: On a side note, it is not clear to me why you join a table with a list of fixed values, isn't it more efficient to just put them (the values) under a where clause?

Comment: Please post some sample data of table Allowance and your expected result. From question it is hard to determine VALUE column.

Comment: Please show the original table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
select s.name, coalesce(v.name, s.name) AS Name1, v.value
from (select name,
             sum(case when Allowance in (1) then value end) as value_1,
             sum(case when Allowance in (1, 2) then value end) as value_2
      from Allowance s
      group by name
     ) s left join
     (values ('A', 'Allowance1', value_1),
             ('A', 'Allowance2', value_2)
     ) v(old_name, name, value)
     on v.old_name = s.name
```